# How to install android-build-tools-33.0.x on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, android

I'm trying to use Apache Cordova to create an android application.

I can't use normal packages because they are too old.
I installed NVM for multiple versions of node.js and gradle 7.6, but now I'm stuck with "No usable Android build tools found. Highest 33.x installed version is 27.0.3; Recommended version is 33.0.2."

There are installer packages, for example here :
https://pkgs.org/download/google-android-build-tools-33.0.0-installer
and :
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/23.10/ubuntu-multiverse-amd64/google-android-build-tools-33.0.0-installer_33.0.0-1686227321_amd64.deb.html

But this is not for my Lubuntu (LSB Version: core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch)

I searched, there were many packages with old versions and one with no version. I hoped this one would ask the user which version he wanted :

```
sudo apt-cache search google-android-build-tools
google-android-build-tools-17-installer - Google build tools 17 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-18-installer - Google build tools 18 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-19-installer - Google build tools 19 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-20-installer - Google build tools 20 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-21-installer - Google build tools 21 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-22-installer - Google build tools 22 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-23-installer - Google build tools 23 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-24-installer - Google build tools 24 for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
google-android-build-tools-installer - Google build tools for Android (aapt, aidl, dexdump, dx)
```

It does nothing useful. It removed :

```
Removing android-sdk (28.0.2+6) ...
Removing android-sdk-build-tools (29.0.3+6) ...
Removing aapt (1:10.0.0+r36-3) ...
Removing zipalign (1:10.0.0+r36-1) ...
```

Then it puts a folder called google-android-build-tools-installer in /usr/share with nothing in it except a sha file and a Makefile. And this seems to be it, it doesn't appear as a new program and it can't be called from the command line. Malware?

As I can't install android-build-tools-33.0.x with apt, I could try installing it manually (like gradle 7.6). But I can't find it! Can I try a package from another distro? I already have dependencies issues, in fact this is what I'm trying to fix.

Should I install Mantic Minotaur?

(Requested info below)

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                 
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-fonville/android-build-tools/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

What I tried today :

sudo sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platform;android-31"
Says at the beginning (before failing) :
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.5-linux.zip

I got the file, unzipped it. It creates a direcory called platform-tools. This contains adb, fastboot, make_f2fs_casefold, mke2fs.conf, source.properties, etc1tool,  hprof-conv,  make_f2fs  mke2fs, NOTICE.txt, sqlite3 and a sub-directory called lib64 which has a single file, libc++.so

Can I do something with that?

Comment: I don't know much about Ubuntu, but the usual way to download/update SDK components is through the `sdkmanager` from [the command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio) (scroll to the bottom to download).

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: sdkmanager doesn't function. 
sudo sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platform;android-31" returns error after error.